# How to use Bluetooth service discovery in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth

in my project there is a necessity to use the Bluetooth service discovery functionality.how could i add this functionality in a windows form

Comment: Please consider taking the [tour] and have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not home in it but i could recommend a 32feet.net if you have knowledge in Personal Area networking http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Comment: i know stuff like that should be a comment but since i'm incabable of commenting i will have to do this my appology